# How to apply custom (user-defined) scalar function to range in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I've wrote some custom data-conversion functions for my spreadsheet, and want to apply them to ranges to calculate some aggregates, like `SUM()` and `MAX()` without creation of temporary columns/rows.

I've thought, that `ARRAYFORMULA()` does trick, like `ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(MY_UDF(A1:A10)))`, but it doesn't work - my functions get arrays as arguments, not single values.

I could modify each and every my conversion function to accept arrays and return arrays, but it looks silly to have this boilerplate code in each and every function. I know, that I could isolate this boilerplate to separate function (thanks to JavaScript functions-as-first-class-citizens), but even in this case it looks not right, as I need to copy'n'paste this boilerplate from project to project.

Is here any way to apply scalar function to range on per-cell basis directly in formula? Something like `SUM(APPLY(MY_UDF, A1:A10))`?

Comment: To confirm - you want to be able apply a function to a cell before using that new value in an aggregate function?

Comment: @ArunNagarajan Yes, it is exactly what I want.